# download files in azure vm using fileuri

Tags: azure

```
"fileUris": [
                "https://files.blob.core.windows.net/extensions/test.sh"]
```

In an Azure scale set, does this part of extension download the file test.sh to the VM or call it directly from blob storage?

Comment: Is this the custom script extension you are configuring? In my opinion, it's not clear exactly to what `fileUris` refers to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are talking about the custom script extension for Azure virtual machines.

On its [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript) it reads:

> **The Custom Script Extension downloads and executes scripts on Azure
>   virtual machines**. This extension is useful for post deployment
>   configuration, software installation, or any other configuration /
>   management task. Scripts can be **downloaded from Azure storage or
>   GitHub**, or provided to the Azure portal at extension run time. The
>   Custom Script extension integrates with Azure Resource Manager
>   templates, and can also be run using the Azure CLI, PowerShell, Azure
>   portal, or the Azure Virtual Machine REST API.

Highlighted are the relevant parts.

The extension work so that it first downloads and then executes the scripts you provide for it.

**Edit**: If you need to deploy some external resources you can upload them to your GitHub account or an Azure Storage Blob and download/read them from there.

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49004497/5403693) for  more details on how to download a file from a blob.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://jasondisk2.blob.core.windows.net/msi/01.PNG -outfile 'C:\'
```

If you simply want to read the json file, then you can do as described here in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37763324/5403693).

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://yadayada:8080/bla"
$response.flag
```

**Note**: `Invoke-RestMethod` automatically converts the json response to a `psobject`.

As for the working directory. The extension downloads its files into the following directory

```
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.*\Downloads\<n>
```

where `<n>` is a decimal integer which may change between executions of the extension. The `1.*` value matches the actual, current `typeHandlerVersion` value of the extension.

For example, the actual directory could be

```
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.8\Downloads\2
```

See the [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript#troubleshoot) section in the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript) for more information.

Alternatively, for a Linux based system the path is similar to

```
/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0/
```

see this page for more [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript#troubleshooting).

Comment: i have a json file which will be read by script.Do I need to make a tar file including both confi.json and script and upload in blob storage. Also will I be able to read the json file from the script using cat command inside the script.What will be the location of downloaded file in VM.

Comment: I need the location of downloaded file in linux machine.

Comment: Added that part

Comment: So, when I run a custom script using "commandToExecute" in template, then does the script automatically run from this location.